# WebClient.DownloadFile in BackgroundWorker performance unacceptable

Tags: .net, webclient, backgroundworker

I have a WinForms application that needs to download many (tens of thousands) fairly large (multi-MB) files per day. I wrote a simple test using the following code:

```
using (var wc = new System.Net.WebClient())
{
    foreach (string url in UrlsToDownload())
    {
        string targetPath = SafeFilePathOf(url);
        wc.DownloadFile(url, targetPath);
    }
}
```

The target machine has a 1 Gb/s connection, but testing shows a sustained download of about 1MB/s. This is less than what I was expecting, but the source servers may have slower connections. A full day's download will require several hours of connectivity, which is acceptable. Network utilization is fairly constant at about 1%:

[image: DownloadFile in UI thread]

However, I need to perform downloads in a background thread and support cancelling and download progress. The .Net `System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker` seems designed for this, so I put the exact same code in a `BackgroundWorker` instance and call `RunWorkerAsync`:


[image: DownloadFile in BackgroundWorker]

Download performance plummets to about 0.05 MB/s. A day's work will require about a week to perform; this is not going to fly.

Why is `BackgroundWorker` performance so bad? Neither the CPU nor network is overloaded. The application is not blocked, I simply moved the download code from the UI thread to a  `BackgroundWorker`. Calling `backgroundWorker.Priority = ThreadPriority.AboveNormal` has no effect.

Comment: There is no difference in network performance being it on any thread, I think its other code of reporting perfomance etc that may be slowing thread. Can you post your full source of BG thread?

Comment: CPU load shot up from 1% to 9%.  Solve that first.

Comment: I recommend you to use the async version - *DownloadFileAsync* anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Network activity performs same whether it's background thread or UI thread. The problem can be any other code of reporting progress or logging activity etc. That may block the thread.

Comment: Both you and Hans had the right idea; it's not the BackgroundWorker, it was my logger. The UI thread test had an empty log file, the BackgroundWorker thread was trying to parse a multi-MB log file after each download. Argh!

Answer (score 1):

Increase the connection limit on the WebClient:

```
internal class CustomWebClient : WebClient
{
    public CustomWebClient()
    {
    }

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri uri)
    {
        HttpWebRequest w = (HttpWebRequest)base.GetWebRequest(uri);

        w.ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit = 100;
        return w;
    }
}
```